# WPF DataTemplate Layout

Tags: wpf, layout, dockpanel

I am creating ListBoxItem rows, each containing these 3 items:

```
1) Button
2) TextBox
3) CheckBox
```

I want them to look like this, where the checkbox docks to the right:

```
| 1 222           3 |
| 1 222222222     3 |
| 1 222222        3 |
```

But instead I am getting this:

```
| 1 222 3           |
| 1 222222222 3     |
| 1 222222 3        |
```

Here is my ItemTemplate:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate x:Name="foo" DataType="{x:Type bar}">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
      <Button DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
      <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
      <TextBlock Text="Foo" />
    </DockPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Admittedly, I don't fully understand the nuances of StackPanels/DockPanels/Grids, but any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to the listbox definition:

```
HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
```

This will allow the items to use the whole horizontal width of the listbox.